# How to get ConTeXt "title" section into table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, context

I'm trying the following code:

```
\setuphead[subject][incrementnumber=yes, number=no]
\setuphead[title][incrementnumber=yes, number=no]
\setupcombinedlist[content][list={title,subject}]

\starttext
\completecontent
\startbodymatter

\starttitle[title={This is a Title}]
This is the Title text.
\stoptitle

\startsubject[title={This is a Subject}]
This is the Subject text.
\stopsubject

\stopbodymatter
\stoptext
```

Why does the *subject* part of this document show up in the table of contents but the *title* part does not?

Then, if I further wrap `\completecontent` inside `\startfrontmatter` and `\stopfrontmatter`, then the table of contents becomes blank?

Comment: Oh ... ugh. The [reference](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Table_of_Contents#Including_unnumbered_heads_in_the_ToC) I was reading was wrong. I should use `incrementnumber=list` instead of `incrementnumber=yes`. ConTeXt seems to have this pervasive problem of poor/wrong/non-existent documentation.

Comment: The wiki page that you linked says that you should use `incrementnumber=yes` for mkii and `incrementnumber=list` for mkiv.

Comment: I don't see this. Where?

Comment: In the paragraph above the example that starts with `mode=mkiv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `incrementnumber=list` instead of `incrementnumber=yes`.

Comment: This should be an addition to the question or this 'answer' should be extended

Comment: For title or subject?

Comment: Actually, I'd like to delete my answer if I have to amend it (plus I don't see the delete button), because I don't know why "line" works and "yes" doesn't. I saw an example somewhere, tried it and it worked.